# Prove that ${\mathbb{Q}}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Prove that ${\mathbb{Q}}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$

I know we will use $A_p$'s for solution. But i dont know how to do the isomorphism between ${\mathbb{Q}}/{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$.

Comment: This is false. Did you mean $\oplus_p \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$? If so, for starters can you identify a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$?

Comment: Yes its my bad sorry.

Comment: I think the subgroup is $A_p$ can be the subgroup of Q/Z consisting of elements of order a power of p.

Comment: Yes, that's right (and that's the unique answer). Can you write down a map from $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}[p^{\infty}]$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ using this, then show it's injective and surjective?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the exponential map

$$
\mathbf{exp} \colon t \in \Bbb R \mapsto e^{i2\pi t} \in  S^1
$$

is a surjective group homomorphism with kernel $\Bbb Z$, hence

$$
S^1 = \Bbb R/\Bbb Z.
$$

Via this correspondence, elements of $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ are complex elements of absolute value $1$ of the form $e^{i2\pi p/q}$ with $p/q \in \Bbb Q$. Can you think of a way to embed $\Bbb Z[p^\infty]$ in $S^1$?

> Note that elements of the form $e^{i2\pi r}$ with rational $r$ are roots of unity, and conversely roots of unity also have this expression. Maybe you can 'classify' roots of unity in terms of primes?

**Hint':** Note that $\Bbb Z[p^\infty]$ is the $p$-torsion of $\Bbb Q/ \Bbb Z$, then use primary decomposition. This may be easier to do with the aforemention description (or not).

**Hint'':** show that if $\xi_n$ and $\xi_m$ are primitive roots of unity of coprime orders $n$ and $m$, then $\xi_n\xi_m$ is primitive of order $nm$. Deduce that any root of unity is a finite product of powers of primitive roots of unity of order $p^r$ for $p$ prime and $r \geq 0$. Use that to construct a map $\bigoplus_p \Bbb Z[p^\infty] \to S^1$ whose image is (the isomorphic copy of) $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$, prove that it is also injective.

Comment: This seems like a way to rewrite the problem, not a hint for the problem.

Comment: @runway44 I've added some extra hints; please do tell if you feel my answer remains unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to provide some interesting context.

You may be familiar with *partial fraction decomposition* for rational functions. Any rational function $f/g$ is expressible as $f(T)/g(T)=p(T)+\sum a_k(T)/\pi_k(T)^{e_k}$ where $p(T)$ is a polynomial, $g(T)=\prod_k \pi_k(T)^{e_k}$ is a factorization into irreducible polynomials, and $a_k(T)$s are polynomials with $\deg a_k< e_k\deg \pi_k$ (so none of the summands can be partial-fractioned more in this fashion). One could choose to reduce $a(T)/\pi(T)^e$ to the form $\sum_{1<j\le e} a_j/\pi(T)^j$ for some scalar coefficients $a_j$.

Ultimately, if $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, this can be phrased as $\mathbb{F}(T)/\mathbb{F}[T]=\bigoplus \mathbb{F}[\pi(T)^{-1}]/\mathbb{F}[T]$.

Similarly, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ can be phrased as follows: every rational number $f/g$ is uniquely expressible as $f/g=n+\sum a_k/p_k^{e_k}$ for some integer $n$, factorization $g=\prod p_k^{e_k}$, and coefficients $0<a_k<p_k^{e_k}$, and we can rewrite $b/p^e$ as $\sum_{1\le j\le e} b_j/p^j$ for coefficients $0<b_j<p$ if desired.

You can solve for the $a_k$s by multiplying $f/g$ by $p_k^{e_k}$ and reducing mod $p_k^{e_k}$.